# How can I have bootstrap textarea that will expand for all the column in a row

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, xhtml

I have the following bootstrap table, I want to add a textarea for a row.
But that text area should expand to all the columns. I have included a image example.

For row 2  I want to have the 4 columns and the textarea. text area should cover all the column as show in the image below.

Is it possible to do[image: Table Example]?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="state" data-radio="true"></th>
            <th data-field="name">Name</th>
            <th data-field="starts">Stars</th>
            <th data-field="forks">Forks</th>
            <th data-field="description">Description</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="radioGroup"></td>
            <td>
                <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table">bootstrap-table</a>
            </td>
            <td>526</td>
            <td>122</td>
            <td>An extended Bootstrap table with radio, checkbox, sort, pagination, and other added features. (supports twitter bootstrap v2 and v3) 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" checked></td>
            <td>
                <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select">multiple-select</a>
            </td>
            <td>288</td>
            <td>150</td>
            <td>A jQuery plugin to select multiple elements with checkboxes :)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="radioGroup"></td>
            <td>
                <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-show-password">bootstrap-show-password</a>
            </td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Show/hide password plugin for twitter bootstrap.
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in the following way--
Add `colspan=12` to your `<td>` which contains the `textarea` and give the text area `width:100%`

**Working snippet**

```css
textarea {
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="state" data-radio="true"></th>
            <th data-field="name">Name</th>
            <th data-field="starts">Stars</th>
            <th data-field="forks">Forks</th>
            <th data-field="description">Description</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="radioGroup"></td>
            <td>
                <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table">bootstrap-table</a>
            </td>
            <td>526</td>
            <td>122</td>
            <td>An extended Bootstrap table with radio, checkbox, sort, pagination, and other added features. (supports twitter bootstrap v2 and v3) 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" checked></td>
            <td>
                <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select">multiple-select</a>
            </td>
            <td>288</td>
            <td>150</td>
            <td>A jQuery plugin to select multiple elements with checkboxes :)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="radioGroup"></td>
            <td>
                <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-show-password">bootstrap-show-password</a>
            </td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Show/hide password plugin for twitter bootstrap.
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
    <td colspan="12">
    <textarea></textarea>
    </td>
    </tr>
       
        </tbody>
    </table>
```